# How to finish this job in emacs?

Tags: emacs

The original string is like this:

```
  # chrom,name,strand,txStart
```

And the result should looks like this:

```
 # $1: chrom
 # $2: name
 # $3: strand
 # $4: txStart
```

Does anyone have idea of a quick way to do that?

Comment: Is there always only four words, or an arbitrary number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lots of ways.

You could use a search and replace making use of the `\#` counter in the replacement. That's zero-based, so you'd either need to add a dummy replacement at the front to use up the zero, or else use the elisp replacement expression `\,(1+ \#)` instead.

You could use a keyboard macro, and insert a counter with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> or <kbd><f3></kbd>. You can seed that counter by supplying a prefix argument when you start recording.

On Emacs 24 you can number the lines of a marked region using a custom format string with <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>, so your format string could be `# $%1d:`

Answer (score 1):

Evaluate following code and execute `foo` function on input line.

```
(require 'cl)

(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((str (buffer-substring-no-properties
               (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position)))
         (words-str (and (string-match "# \\(.+\\)$" str)
                         (match-string 1 str)))
         (buf (get-buffer-create "*tmp*")))
    (unless words-str
      (error "Line should be '# word1,word2,...'"))
    (with-current-buffer buf
      (erase-buffer)
      (loop with index = 1
            for word in (split-string words-str ",")
            do
            (progn
              (insert (format "# $%d: %s\n" index word))
              (incf index)))
      (pop-to-buffer buf))))
```